# Error spotting : The drawings are very good ; almost everyone of them deserves a gold medal

Tags: relative-pronouns, exam-questions

> The drawings are very good ;(a) almost everyone (b) of them deserves a gold medal.(c) No error (d)

Is this sentence grammatically correct ?

I googled for this sentence but couldn't find any definite answer , although none of the sites is a reliable source some said error is in part A some said in part B and some even said it's error free.

Comment: The error is *everyone* = "all people" instead of *every one* = "each".

Comment: @StoneyB I had exact thing in my mind but what if the speaker is referring to artists ? Everyone = every artist.

Comment: @user212388 - It doesn't make sense if the speaker is referring to artists - the sentence begins "the **drawings** are very good", so the only thing that *them* could reasonably refer to is the the drawings.  Also, when we're using "everyone" to mean "all the people", we don't say "of them", because that doesn't make sense: *all the people of them*?

Answer (score 4):

The error is "everyone".  It should be "every one".

"Everyone" means "all people", which does not apply here since the speaker is talking about the paintings.  In this case he means "each painting".

Note the difference here:

> Everyone deserves a medal.  (all of you)
>
> Every one of you deserves a medal.  (each of you)

Both of these have the same *meaning* but the details are different.  The first "all" is *collective*, while the second "each" is *individual*, which changes the *nuance*.

> Everyone is going to the game.
>
> Every one of us is going to the game.

The second sentence emphasizes that, individually, we each chose to go to the game.  The first sentence is more a simple statement of who is going.

Comment: Pardon me but I couldn't judge the difference between all of you and each of you . Both sentences convey to me that every person in group deserves a medal.

Comment: Yes, both sentences mean the same thing, but the details are different.  "All" is collective, while "each" is individual.  I'll edit my answer.